# Angular way to capture Id if child being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm new to Angular 1.0 and I'm coming from jQuery backgroud.

Let's say I have following HTML :

```
<div id="filters">
    <div id="filter1">Filter 1</div>
    <div id="filter2">Filter 2</div>
    <div id="filter3">Filter 3</div>
    <div id="filter4">Filter 4</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to have a function which will return id of child element being clicked.
What could be the Angular way to best implement the following jQuery code :

```
$('#filters div').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a directive which you attach to the parent and this directive could bind to the onClick event for all the children.

```js
function getChildrenid() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      var children = element[0].querySelectorAll('div'); //get all child div's
      angular.forEach(children, function(child) { //loop over all the child
        var ngElement = angular.element(child); //create an angular element of the child
        ngElement.on('click', function() { //bind to the click event
          console.log(ngElement.attr('id'));
        });
      });
    }
  };
}

function MainController() {
  //
}

angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app')
  .controller('MainController', MainController)
  .directive('getChildrenid', getChildrenid);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
    <div id="filters" get-childrenid>
        <div id="filter1">Filter 1</div>
        <div id="filter2">Filter 2</div>
        <div id="filter3">Filter 3</div>
        <div id="filter4">Filter 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could use an ngRepeat to render the children instead of listing them all separately and on the repeated children you could add an ngClick.

You could add an ngClick to each child element separately.

Comment: As per your 1st approach, can I bind the directive to some specific child click event ? If yes, could you help me with a quick code snippet.

Comment: @JaspreetSingh I added an example of the first approach.

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved from writing ngClick 25 times. There is a reason I couldn't use ngRepeat though.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to do is create an array and loop it through the DOM using `ng-repeat` then you can pass the object as parameter to click function and get the id

```
<div id="filters">
    <div ng-click="check(item)" ng-repeat="item in arr" id="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</div> 
</div>
```

sample array

```
[{"name":"Filter 1","id":"filter1"},{"name":"Filter 2","id":"filter2"},{"name":"Filter 3","id":"filter3"},{"name":"Filter 4","id":"filter4"}]
```

if you don't want to use the ng repeat then i suggest pass the `$event.target` as the parameter to the click event

```
<div id="filters">
    <div id="filter1" ng-click="getID($event.target)">Filter 1</div>
    <div id="filter2" ng-click="getID($event.target)">Filter 2</div>
    <div id="filter3" ng-click="getID($event.target)">Filter 3</div>
    <div id="filter4" ng-click="getID($event.target)">Filter 4</div>
</div>
```

The function

```
$scope.getID = function(item){
   console.log(item.id)
};
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.arr = [{"name":"Filter 1","id":"filter1"},{"name":"Filter 2","id":"filter2"},{"name":"Filter 3","id":"filter3"},{"name":"Filter 4","id":"filter4"}]


$scope.check = function(item){ 
    console.log(item.id)
}

$scope.getID = function(item)
{
    console.log(item.id)
};
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<p> using ng repeat </p>
 <div id="filters">
    <div ng-click="check(item)" ng-repeat="item in arr" id="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</div> 
</div>
<br>

<p> using $event </p>
<div id="filters">
    <div id="filter1" ng-click="getID($event.target)">Filter 1</div>
    <div id="filter2" ng-click="getID($event.target)">Filter 2</div>
    <div id="filter3" ng-click="getID($event.target)">Filter 3</div>
    <div id="filter4" ng-click="getID($event.target)">Filter 4</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In angular, when you click on an element, you get an *event* object.

This object has a *toElement* property that gives you the element that received the event. You can then simply use *toElement.id* to display the id:

```js
function MyController() {
  this.getId = function(event) {
    console.log(event.toElement.id);
  }
}

angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <div id="filters" ng-click="ctrl.getId($event)">
        <div id="filter1">Filter 1</div>
        <div id="filter2">Filter 2</div>
        <div id="filter3">Filter 3</div>
        <div id="filter4">Filter 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, You have bind the function to whole parent. If I add some additional child elements such as <a>, <p> etc., clicking them will also be trigger the function.
I want to bind it to the specific child.

Answer (score 2):

In you angularJs controller define a function that gets an event and specify `ng-click` directive on the divs like

```
<div id="filters">
    <div id="filter1" data-ng-click="ShowId($event)">Filter 1</div>
    <div id="filter2" data-ng-click="ShowId($event)">Filter 2</div>
    <div id="filter3" data-ng-click="ShowId($event)">Filter 3</div>
    <div id="filter4" data-ng-click="ShowId($event)">Filter 4</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.ShowId = function(event)
{
   alert(event.target.id);
};
```

Comment: I don't want to go on and write ngClick for each and every child as I have many. Couldn't it be a better approach as we follow in jQuery, like bind just 1 function to `$('#filters div')` ? Or I have to just use that custom directive for parent element approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custome `directive` on your parent `div`. This directive will give you the access to the `DOM` element. This is recommended `angular` way for accessing `DOM` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-click` directive to pass event. Like this

```
<div id="filters" ng-click="myFunction($event)">
   <div id="filter1">Filter 1</div>
   <div id="filter2">Filter 2</div>
   <div id="filter3">Filter 3</div>
   <div id="filter4">Filter 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's **a minimal approach** in which the ID is directly passed from the HTML template. This way, you can keep your controller as clean as possible and you don't need to create any additional directives.

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as $ctrl">
    <div id="filters">
      <div id="filter1" ng-click="$ctrl.showId($event.target.id)">Filter 1</div>
      <div id="filter2" ng-click="$ctrl.showId($event.target.id)">Filter 2</div>
      <div id="filter3" ng-click="$ctrl.showId($event.target.id)">Filter 3</div>
      <div id="filter4" ng-click="$ctrl.showId($event.target.id)">Filter 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script>
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function() {
      this.showId = function(id) {
        console.log(id);
      }
    });
</script>
```